# Computercraft Lua change nil to 0

Tags: lua, computercraft

I am using Computercraft, a Minecraft mod, and I needed help with something. I am attempting to find all peripherals of a type, get the energy from them, and add them together. However, I get a "attempt to perform arithmetic on nill" or something error. Here is my code:

```
local periList = peripheral.getNames()
energy = 0
totalenergy = 0

for i = 1, #periList do
  if peripheral.getType(periList[i]) == "cofh_thermalexpansion_energycell" then
    local cell = peripheral.wrap(periList[i])
    print(periList[i])
    if cell.getEnergyStored("potato") ~= "nil" then
      energy = cell.getEnergyStored("potato")
      print(cell.getEnergyStored("potato"))
    else
      energy = 0
      print(0)
    end
    totalenergy = totalenergy + energy
  end
end
print(totalenergy)
```

Sorry, codebox didn't work

Anyways, does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nil` and `"nil"` are two different things.

The former is the `nil` type "singleton" the latter is a string of three characters. They are not equivalent.

Try dropping the quotes from the `if` line.

Also you can assign (the potential) `nil` to `energy` and then directly `energy` and set it to 0 if it is `nil` (or even just use

```
energy = cell.getEnergyStored("potato") or 0
```

directly since `nil` is a "false-y" value so `nil or 0` evaluates to `0`).

Comment: Yep, just removing the quotes worked. Thanks! How can I mark as solved?

Comment: @NathanielButterfield There should be a check mark under the voting arrows next to the answer that you can click on to accept the answer.